# Как правильно записать через тернарный оператор условие в атрибуте

Tags: ruby

Я сделал атрибут в теге свой и мне нужно применить внутри условие, как правильно его записать? Т.к. выдает много ошибок

```
data-color_url="<%= check_url == true  ? '/product/<%= color_articul %>/main_image/view_<%= color_articul %>.png' : '/desktop/img/product.png' %>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то у Вас какой-то винегрет из **Html** и **Ruby**...

Вы внутри Ruby-вставки пытаетесь делать еще Ruby-вставки. Да и условие можно упростить.

Как-то так:

```
data-color_url = "<%= check_url  ? "/product/#{color_articul}/main_image/view_#{color_articul}.png" : "/desktop/img/product.png" %>"
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже разобрался